# Is it necessary to percent encode a URI before sending it to the browser?

Tags: html, web, browser

Is it necessary to percent encode a URI before using it in the browser i.e when we write a URI in a browser should it already be percent encoded or it is the responsibility of the browser to encode the URI and send the request to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that most modern browsers will accept a non-encoded URL and they will generally be able to encode reserved characters themselves.

However, it is bad practice to rely on this because you can end up with unpredictable results. For instance, if you were sending form data to a server using a `GET` request and someone had typed in a `#` symbol, the browser will interpret that differently if it was encoded or non-encoded.

In short, it's always best to encode data manually to get predictable results if you're expecting reserved characters in a request. Fortunately most programming languages used on the web have built in functions for this.

Just to add, you don't need to encode the whole URL - it's usually the data you're sending in a `GET` request which gets encoded. For example:

`http://www.foo.com?data=This%20is%20my%20encoded%20string%20%23`